# Convert GLSL to C or C++

Tags: c++, c, glsl, shader

as an exercise I am trying to convert GLSL shaders into plain c/c++ than can be executed via the CPU instead of the GPU, regardless if this is much less efficient and slower.

Given that the data in c/c++ will be stored into an unsigned int array of pixels, how can I convert the next line to something that will perform the same operation in plain c?

```
// GLSL

vec2 test = vec2(0.5, 0.2);
vec2 coord = vec2(0.5, 0.5);
vec3 output_color = texture2D(u_texture, coord - test).rgb
```

I could only get up to this

```
// C/C++

short vec2_test_x = 127; // Equivalent to 0.5
short vec2_test_y = 51;  // Equivalent to 0.2

short vec2_coord_x = 127; // Equivalent to 0.5
short vec2_coord_y = 127; // Equivalent to 0.5

short color_r, color_g, color_b;
int output_color = pixels[.... No idea how to continue....]    
......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking about is a memory-mapping-function. The following formula will do the trick:

```
int output_color = pixels[vec2_coord_y * 256 + vec2_coord_x];

//assuming output_color is stored in format XXBBGGRR:
color_r = (output_color & 0x000000FF);
color_g = (output_color & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
color_b = (output_color & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
```

Comment: Hi Marius, could you please explain me a bit more how it works so I can understand it? About "vec2_coord_y * 256", why times 256?

Comment: I think this is the width of your texture since you wrote `short vec2_coord_x = 127; // Equivalent to 0.5`